# Custom field saving

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a problem with Django admin, basically i have a model like team -> motorcycle connection, and now i have a lot of motorcycles and instead of inline objects i just put custom template with checkbox and manually added objects to database. Now for "hack" i have following line in my custom template:

```
<div id="divCheckbox" style="display: none;">
  {{ inline_admin_formset.formset }}
</div>
```

and it works okay, but it takes a lot of time if there are many objects, if i remove the "hack" i get **MultiValueDictKeyError**. So for the saving in model i just overwrite save method, and save after the super.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    super(MotorcycleAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    moto_instert = Motorcycle()
    moto_instert.benefit = obj
    moto_instert.store = Motorcycle.get_by_team_id(id)
    moto_instert.save()
```

So is there any way i can ignore this fields which i am saving manually or which way should i solve the problem?

Comment: Do yout need to call `save_model()` once for every checked checkbox? If so, you could write a loop in your `views.py()` that calls `save_model()` for each checked element in your http.POST data.

Comment: I call it at the main model, not in the stackedinline model. So its called only once, after you edit the main model

Comment: Thought about to create a new instance for each checked checkbox? You can call it recursive-like from you're `save_model()`. Just check if you have got multiple checked items (a `list` of items e.g.) and create a new model-instance for every checked item where you call it's `save_model()` with the needed data but only a single checked item.